# How to resume multiple download using PersistableTransfer manager in amazon s3 in android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, download

I am downloading a list of objects using following function:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3client);
        try {

            GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, entity.getName());
            download = transferManager.download(getRequest, f, new S3ProgressListener() {


                @Override
                public void onPersistableTransfer(PersistableTransfer arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    saveTransferState(arg0,  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+entity.getName());
                }
                @Override
                public void progressChanged(
                        com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent arg0) {

                    long transferred = arg0.getBytesTransferred();
                    Log.d("AWS3", "" + transferred);
                }
            });
```

Now when my internet connection stops while downloads were in progress i pause this download and resume it when internet connection again available using following code:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(S3Getter.s3client);
             String bucket = "Short_Films";
            String key = entity.getName();
            String[] parts = key.split("/");
            String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

            final String full_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+entity.getName();
            File file = new File(full_path);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            if(file.exists()) {
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    PersistableDownload persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis); 
                    S3Getter.download = transferManager.resumeDownload(persistableUpload);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Now the problem is this code works fine to resume single object. But when there are multiple objects to resume it resume only last resumed object.

I am stuck at this point.
Please some body help me.....

Comment: is any body there to help me?

Comment: check this tutorial here http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2Y9J2CUDVJ5LZ/Pausing-and-Resuming-transfers-using-Transfer-Manager maybe it will helps .